# add Variable into Context, or define local variable, in DustJS?

Tags: javascript, dust.js

In my dustJS template, I make use of a combination of variable to use it as a new variable.
For example, say if I have `pname` and `cname`, then I want to create `name = pname + cname`.
Additionally.. I may want to create local variable based on certain condition, for example, `name = {?.rep} pname {:else} pname + name {/.rep}`. I may want to pass these variables into helpers.

To stick to the DRY principle, the best option would be to create local so that I can refer to this local variable later when it appears again.

I tried out with partials, something like: `{<name}pname + cname{/name}`, and use it later as `{+name/}`. But this way doesn't work with helpers, as well as the conditional block.

I think one possible solution might be that.. adding variables into the current context using helpers, but I don't know how to do.

So my question here is: how to add variable into current context, or how to define a local variable on the fly?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

@provide helper from [dust-motes repo](https://github.com/rragan/dust-motes/tree/master/src/helpers/data/provide) should help you solve this issue.

If for some reason @provide helper does not work for you, take a look at the proposed [@addToContext](https://github.com/linkedin/dustjs-helpers/pull/57) helper in dustjs-helpers repo.@addToContext helper modifies context, so if you are not careful it might override context data with the same keys. @provide helper is preferred to @addToContext.